# inserting data from an array without loop like while or for each

Tags: php, database, request

I have a little problem that I encounter
and to this day I have never met before.

For obvious reasons I had to save some data
from my DB via a loop (a new recording
at each iteration).

Today I reworked (me or a user of the platform)
data.

So I have a table physical, no I meant virtual but HTML ()
which takes different posts. These posts are all labels and field names associated are not designed in the form of a table as
the recording is done in a single line. So the names of my labels
are in the form name = "text" rather than name = "data [$ i] text."

The trouble is that during the Indexation in the database,
I have a simple request INSERT INTO and I know the text fields that will
receive data but the problem is during the insertion I have an array
that looks like this:

```
array
  'poste' => string 'Principal' (length=9)
  'ordre' => string '1' (length=1)
array
  'poste' => string 'Intérêts' (length=8)
  'ordre' => string '2' (length=1)
array
  'poste' => string 'Clause pénale' (length=13)
  'ordre' => string '3' (length=1)
```

How indicate how to make sure that Indexation happens
correctly, knowing that the key may change at any time based
order that is defined (fields order).

how to specify for example the array contents meeting the criteria
post = Main
should be allocated to field ordre_main?

I thought about doing a query per iteration (I have a half) but I
think it will be a bit heavy.

I know it may seem odd to make a loop and linearize
data into a single record but this time I had no choice I had
this constraint.

Thank you in advance for your help and advice.

SP.
Elephant

Comment: and a good *Elephant* to you sir.

Comment: Sorry, i don't get it. What are you trying to accomplish? It sounds to me like your db design could use some work...

Comment: In fact I have an array and I'm trying to save data from this array in a signle request with no loop like while or for each

Comment: Can you share your database table structure and any code that you might be trying. What role does `ordre` plays?

Comment: ordre mean in french order. In fact there it is the order of appear.  I'm sorry verry much for my bad english. The structure of the table I use Is like that I have a table called `ventilation` And I have in this table many rows with two column. 'label' and 'order' ...

The thing is that in the next step I need to save all rows to one single row in a next table.